# How to dump the data from DB2 to Cassandra more faster in nifi

Tags: cassandra, db2, apache-nifi

I have a requirement where I need to load data from DB2 to Cassandra using Apache Nifi.
My DB2 table has around 40k records which has taken around 15 mins to complete the data dump to cassandra.
I have attached 2 images of current nifi flow for this usecase. Observed only 100+ records are read/sec.
Could anyone please let me know -  how to tune the flow/processors so that we can increase the speed (reduce time) of data dump.

1. [DB2 to Cassandra Nifi Flow -  Before Execute script starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqY7H.png)
2. [After Execute script started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTDjj.png)

Am attaching execute script where we are preparing insert statements for Cassandra dump.

```
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
import json
import csv
import io
import datetime

class TransformCallback(StreamCallback):
    def _init_(self):
        pass
    def process(self,inputStream,outputStream):
        inputdata = IOUtils.toString(inputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        text = csv.reader(io.StringIO(inputdata))
        l = []
        for row in text:
            mon = row[0].strip()
            modified_date = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(mon), "%d%b%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
            row[0] = modified_date
            row[1] = row[1].strip()
            row[2] = row[2].strip()
            l.append(row)
        values_str = json.dumps(l)
        leng = len(l)
        for i in range(leng):
            obj = json.loads(values_str)[i]  ## obj = dict
            newObj = {
                  "date": obj[0],
                  "max": obj[1],
                  "city": obj[2]
                }
            insert_query = ("INSERT INTO model.test_data JSON '"+json.dumps(newObj , indent=4)+"';").encode('utf-8')
            outputStream.write(bytearray(insert_query))


flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile,TransformCallback())
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename",flowFile.getAttribute('filename').split('.')[0]+'_result.json')
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: You have to show your current flow and bottlenecks in it.

Comment: I have attached the current flow. I am facing bottleneck only at the start of execute script.

Comment: Then your question is more about python )

Comment: First problem that you loading whole file into the memory in this line `IOUtils.toString(inputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` . Is it large?

Comment: Actually I am splitting my file into seperate lines using **SplitLine** processor before ExecuteScript processor. So I believe this line reads only one line at a time
IOUtils.toString(inputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I have added 2 screenshot images in my above post - records before and after ExecuteScript processor starts.

Comment: Instead of `session.get()` you could use `session.get(1000)`. Where 1000 is number of files to try to get from incoming queue. It'll give you some bonus. Could you show an example of incoming and output data of ExecuteScript?

Comment: **Incoming Data of ExecuteScript:**  
  2-Dec-15,120, Albuquerque

Comment: **Output Data of ExecuteScript:**  

INSERT INTO model.test_data JSON '{  
    "date": "2015-12-02",   
    "max": "120",  
    "city": "Albuquerque"  
}

Comment: it's possible to use standard processors: `ConvertRecord` to convert csv record to json and then `ReplaceText` to add `INSERT INTO ...`. If you want to do your own code - I could help with groovy (not python).

Comment: Yes @daggett I would require your help on writing code with groovy as I don't have knowledge on this language. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that the required transformation possible to do with two standard processors:

- `ConvertRecord` to convert csv record to json
- `ReplaceText` to add INSERT INTO ...

If you still want to use scripting, I could help with groovy.
The following scripts are for `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor.

---

**processes one flow file per call**

it converts all lines from flow file, so, not required to split file by lines before this processor.

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

ff.write{rawIn, rawOut->
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){w->
        rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){r->
            //iterate lines from input reader and split each with coma
            r.splitEachLine( ',' ){row->
                //build object (map)
                def obj = [
                    "date": row[0],
                    "max" : row[1],
                    "city": row[2]
                ]
                //convert obj to json string
                def json = JsonOutput.toJson(obj)
                //write data to output
                w << "INSERT INTO model.test_data JSON '" << json << "';" << '\n'
            }
        }
    }
}

REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

---

**processes multiple flow files per call**

similar to previous but with flowfile list handling `fflist.each{ff-> ...}`

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def fflist=session.get(1000)
if(!fflist)return

fflist.each{ff->
    ff.write{rawIn, rawOut->
        rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){w->
            rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){r->
                //iterate lines from input reader and split each with coma
                r.splitEachLine( ',' ){row->
                    //build object (map)
                    def obj = [
                        "date": row[0],
                        "max" : row[1],
                        "city": row[2]
                    ]
                    //convert obj to json string
                    def json = JsonOutput.toJson(obj)
                    //write data to output
                    w << "INSERT INTO model.test_data JSON '" << json << "';" << '\n'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    REL_SUCCESS << ff
}
```